# Show that any $f \in \mathbb{Q}(\langle x \rangle)$ is associate to any $\overline{f} \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $G = \langle x \rangle$ be the infinite cyclic group generated by an element $x$. The group ring $R = \mathbb{Q}(G)$ consists of finite sums of the form $$ r_{-m}x^{-m}+r_{-m+1}x^{-m+1}+\cdots + r_{-1}x^{-1} + r_{0} + r_{1}x + \cdots + r_{n}x^{n} $$

where $m,n \geq 0$ and $r_{-m}$, $r_{-m+1}$, $\cdots$, $r_{n}$ are rational numbers. The ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is naturally embedded in $R$.

I need to prove that any element $f \in R$ is an associate to the polynomial $\overline{f}\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (i.e., $f|\overline{f}$ and $\overline{f}|f$), the only thing is, **I am not entirely sure what $\overline{f}$ is supposed to be in this context.**

Is it some kind of conjugate? Is it just any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? (And so I'm just showing that any of the finite sums in $R$ is associate to any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?)

If someone could explain to me what $\overline{f}$ is supposed to be here, that would help immensely.

Thank you!

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on here out of context. My best guess is that you are suppose to show that $f$ **has** an associate which is a rational polynomial. If so, then take your $f$ and multiply by $x^m$ (which is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}(\langle x \rangle)$) and get $x^m f(x) = \bar{f}(x)$ which is a rational polynomial.

Comment: Often $\bar{f}$ refers to some sort of conjugate, but in your situation it might just be referring to "something vaguely related to $f$" like giving $f$ a hat or prime or tilde etc.

Comment: @BillCook I sort of figured something like what you said in your first comment, so I tried multiplying $f$ by $x^{m}$, and while you get something of the form $\overline{f}$, if you let $f = \sum_{i=-m}^{n}r_{i}x^{i}$ and $\overline{f} = \sum_{0}^{n+m}r_{i}x^{i}$ and multiply $x^{m}f$, you don't get $\overline{f}$ exactly. The coefficients $r_{i}$ are off.

Comment: @BillCook how would you compensate for the coefficients then?

Comment: Why should $\bar{f} = \sum_0^{n+m} r_ix^i$? Is this its definition?

Comment: If you *define* $\bar{f} = x^m f(x) = \sum_0^{n+m} r_{i-m}x^i$ then $f$ and $\bar{f}$ are associates with $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.